# Rails, Silverlight, and cross-domain calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, silverlight

I have a Rails API hosted in Heroku. I also have a .NET console client that issues HTTPRequests (POST) to it just fine. However, I have a Silverlight that needs to do the same, but I keep getting this error:

Code 4004
ManagedRuntimeError

Which apparently is related to crossdomain issues.

Does anybody know what I need to do to get this Silverlight app to work against my Rails API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add a crossdomain.xml and/or clientaccesspolicy.xml file to the root of your rails site.  Add the domain from which you are requesting from with the silverlight app.

Here is an MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

See also this answer: [Cross Domain security error in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428461/cross-domain-security-error-in-silverlight)

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Besides adding the files, we also had a problem with the content-type and the body of the message we were sending.  :)